# setting image in navigation bar

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uinavigationcontroller

Hi I'm new in objective C and using navigation controller in my app. Where I want to set an icon image and title of screen. like

[image]

How can I do this. I've used below code but it does not work as I want. It shows only image in navigation Bar.

```
self.navigationController.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Concate Your Memories", nil);
UIImageView* tileImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"TopBar-icon.png"]];
tileImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 25);
self.navigationItem.titleView = tileImageView;
```

Please help me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have given and everyone else have suggested is correct. But you're assigning the image and title separately. Therefore,

1. Create your own view with your image and a label and assign it as the title view OR
2. Add the title to the image itself and assign it to the titleview like as you are doing now

Answer (score 1):

For Setting Image in Navigation Bar

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"TopBar-icon.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but its not a background image.

Answer (score 0):

that code works properly on iOS7:

```
    [self.navigationItem setTitleView:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo.png"]]];
```

*(tested on real device and simulator as well)*

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own view and set it on the top of screen.
Hide default navigation bar for the whole app.